# Is there a way to suppress `unrecognized argument` errors in pytest?

Tags: pytest

I have a script that loops through a number of projects and executes `pytest ${project} --foo 123`. I need to change the option from `foo` to `bar`. I would like to change the script to  `pytest ${project} --foo 123 --bar 123`, give teams time to switch from using `foo` to `bar`, and then remove `--foo 123`. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you may want to use a `pytest.ini` file at the root folder where you run `pytest`. (More info: https://pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html)

Inside the `pytes.ini` file, you may have something like this:

```ini
[pytest]                                                                                   
                                                                                           
# Display console output and disable cacheprovider:
addopts = --capture=no -p no:cacheprovider
```

The `pytest.ini` file lets you specify args for all tests run with `pytest` so that you don't have to directly specify those in your run commands.

For your case, it may look like this initially:

```ini
[pytest]                                                                                   

addopts = --foo 123 --bar 123
```

Then you can swap out things as needed. To modify your existing scripts that have `foo_abc` in them, (and replace with `bar_abc`), you could use the following script (example for Linux):

Replace all occurrences of "foo_abc" with "bar_xyz" on Linux, for Python files from the current directory:

```bash
sed -i 's/foo_abc/bar_xyz/g' *.py
```

(Other operating systems may have a slight variation on the optimal string replacement command.)

---

To avoid errors if you haven't yet declared `--bar`, you could create a temporary arg in a `conftest.py` file. (Reference: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html)

```py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--bar", action="store", dest="bar_var", default=None
    )
```

And then remove that placeholder when you've actually defined the `--bar` arg.

Comment: Thank you. Those are all excellent suggestions, but I may have removed too much complexity from the problem. I don't have access to conftest.py and pytest.ini (the script is actually passing the pytest command line to a docker container, and each test project is a separate container). I think the easiest way will be to add the `--bar` option to a common plugin. That way there will at least not be any code changes required in individual projects during the transition.

Comment: If your script has the power to install a new python library, you could put the `conftest.py` part in that library and then install it separately so that you have a placeholder for the `--bar`` option until you have a real one available. If the environment is persistent, then you'll need to uninstall that extra library so that you don't have arg conflicts.